# PayPal Refund Transaction Authorisation Issue

Tags: paypal, odoo, odoo-12

I'm working on Odoo version 12.0, developing the process of Refund Sale Transaction using their API. I've taken reference from the following link: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/#sale_refund

But there is some authorization issue with their API of the refund transaction.

I've example request/response parameters like the following:

```
import requests

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json','Authorization': 'Bearer Access-Token'}

data = '{\n  "amount": {\n    "total": "2.34",\n    "currency": "USD"\n  },\n  "invoice_number": "INV-1234567"\n}'

response = requests.post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/2MU78835H4515710F/refund', headers=headers, data=data)
```

It gives me the following response:

```
{'message': 'Authentication failed due to invalid authentication credentials or a missing Authorization header.', 'links': [{'rel': 'information_link', 'href': 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#error'}], 'name': 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILURE'}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

And how to generate bearer token using PayPal Payment API?

Comment: Has anyone know how to test the Paypal Refund transaction as a pending state? As it directly goes to the completed state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Authorization` header needs to contain an *actual* Access Token after the word `'Bearer '`.  Sending the string `'Access Token'` will not work.

Here is how to obtain an actual access token: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-an-access-token

Comment: Thank you very much. I got an answer.

Comment: When I send the request with sandbox account refund transaction API, it gives me error of Permission Denied. Can you please tell me why?

Comment: {'information_link': 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors', 'debug_id': '9db52e4ca61f4', 'message': 'Permission denied.', 'name': 'PERMISSION_DENIED'}

Comment: Check the permissions of the REST App of the Client ID you are using, in https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fapplications .  Make sure you are checking the correct mode, live or sandbox. Also make sure your access token request returns the necessary scope.

Comment: Currently, I'm using Client ID & Secret of https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications But it gives me Permission denied.

Comment: Can you tell me which Client ID & Secret need to use for sandbox account as well as live account ?

Comment: You need to configure them with the appropriate permissions. There are many checkboxes.

Comment: Are you know how to test the "Paypal Refund transaction" as a "pending" state? As it directly goes to the completed state.

Comment: Send yourself a payment with intent=authorization and don't capture it, or send yourself a payment in a funny currency like AUD and don't accept it

Comment: Can't understand well, can you explain more?
Just an FYI: I want to test the "Paypal Refund transaction" with the pending state, not normal transaction.

Comment: I'm not sure why you need to test refunding a transaction in a pending state. That is an odd thing to be testing. But either of those scenarios I described will result in a transaction that is in a pending state.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. Can you please tell me how to check Paypal Client ID and Secret Key is correct or not?

Comment: Because when their credentials are wrong at that time it can't generate a token for the refund process.

Comment: That is another very strange question to be asking. The way to check if a Client ID and Secret are valid is to attempt to generate an Oauth token. If it fails, they are invalid.

Comment: No, but I want to check before the Oauth token generates process.

Comment: Then try to generate one earlier, before you actually need one. The way to check is to generate one, this is not complicated.